# Simple Button Test with Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am just finishing up learning JavaScript on Codecademy.com and I was trying a simple function out with an html button. My problem is that I guess I don't understand how the JS I learned equates to usable code and I've searched these forums and tried the document.getElementById.onclick method and I tried using onClick="adventure();" in the button itself and I cannot get anything to work. Please explain to me how you apply JS to buttons so that it works in a browser. Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("adv").onclick = adventure();

        function adventure() {

            if (confirm('I am ready to play!')) {

            var age = prompt("What's your age?");

            if(age < 18) {
                console.log('I cannot stop you from playing, but do so at your own risk!');
            } else {
                console.log('You have a great challenge, ahead. Brace yourself.' + "\r\n");
            }

            console.log("You are walking down the street and you see Shawn beating up your friends and stealing their candy. You feel as though it is your duty to respond. You walk up to him and say, 'Hey, Shawn, knock it off!" + "\r\n");

            console.log("Shawn glares at you." + "\r\n");

            var choice1 = function() {
            var userAnswer = prompt("Do you wish to fight?" + "\r\n");

            if(userAnswer !== "yes" || userAnswer !== "no") {
                console.log("You must choose 'yes' or 'no'.");
                choice1();
            } else if (userAnswer === "yes") {
                console.log("As you go to kick Shawn, he grabs your leg and slams you to the pavement. As the world turns black and your eyes slowly close, you feel the end is near. You cry, and then perish. Goodbye!");
            } else {
                console.log("Good choice, weakling. By playing the coward you will survive. Now where's my beer?");
            }

            };
        }

        </script>

    </head>


    <body>

        <input id="adv" type="button" onclick="adventure();" value="Start Your Adventure" />

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're just missing a closing `}`.

Comment: An input tag should always be within a form for the HTML to be valid... but I don't think this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line:

```
document.getElementById("adv").onclick = adventure();
```

does not make sense before the tag is defined. Try to remove this line because you already call `adventure` function from `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you query DOM elements *after* they are created. The script tag is executed before the elements are instantiated. So wrap the code in an `.onload`:

```
 window.onload = function() {
     ...
 };
```

Also, `adventure();` will in this case pre-maturely call the function. Pass the function as `adventure` instead:

```
document.getElementById('adv') = adventure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the following line

```
document.getElementById("adv").onclick = adventure();
```

because you have

```
<input id="adv" type="button" onclick="adventure();" value="Start Your Adventure" />
```

Or you can remove the inline event handler `onclick="adventure();"` from the input element and can use

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("adv").onclick = adventure;
}
function adventure()
{
    // code goes here
}
```

For more advanced event handling [**look at this**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers from Tengiz and David are partially correct, but your code is missing a "}", choice1 is not being closed. I created a fiddle to demonstrate. Remove your inline onclick and all should be well.

```
document.getElementById("adv").onclick = adventure;
function adventure() {

            if (confirm('I am ready to play!')) {

            var age = prompt("What's your age?");

            if(age < 18) {
                console.log('I cannot stop you from playing, but do so at your own risk!');
            } else {
                console.log('You have a great challenge, ahead. Brace yourself.' + "\r\n");
            }

            console.log("You are walking down the street and you see Shawn beating up your friends and stealing their candy. You feel as though it is your duty to respond. You walk up to him and say, 'Hey, Shawn, knock it off!" + "\r\n");

            console.log("Shawn glares at you." + "\r\n");

            var choice1 = function() {
                var userAnswer = prompt("Do you wish to fight?" + "\r\n");
            }
            if(userAnswer !== "yes" || userAnswer !== "no") {
                console.log("You must choose 'yes' or 'no'.");
                choice1();
            } else if (userAnswer === "yes") {
                console.log("As you go to kick Shawn, he grabs your leg and slams you to the pavement. As the world turns black and your eyes slowly close, you feel the end is near. You cry, and then perish. Goodbye!");
            } else {
                console.log("Good choice, weakling. By playing the coward you will survive. Now where's my beer?");
            }

            };
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UuBSj/9/

Comment: Also either wrap this code in an window.onload = { //place code here } or move the script to the bottom of the page.